# ejabberd 15 allow registration not only from localhost

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-auth

Hello i'm newbie of ejabberd and i have a problem to solve.
I installed ejabberd 15 on ubuntu (machine1) (my machine has 32 bit and the latest version of ejabberd is not available for my machine) and i cant register user
this is my steps

1) i installed ejabberd and i started the instance

2) i installed a xmpp client (i'm tring with PSI)

3) the registration of new user and the login works perfectly using PSI in local machine

4) i installed PSI in another machine (machine2) and i tried to register a new user but ejabberd says that i havent permission for this operation

5) then i registered a new user using the administration web interface and i tried to login with this new user from the machine2 and now the user can login

Note: the machine1 is behind a nat and i access trought port forwarding configuration (but is't not problem because i repeat the second user can login if registered with the administration web interface)

it would seem that i have to change some parameter in the yaml configuration file of ejabberd but what?

i post the complete configuration  file, thanks

```
  ###   ACCESS RULES
    access:
         ## Maximum number of simultaneous sessions allowed for a single user:
      max_user_sessions: 
        all: 10
  ## Maximum number of offline messages that users can have:
  max_user_offline_messages: 
    admin: 5000
    all: 100
  ## This rule allows access only for local users:
  local: 
    local: allow
  ## Only non-blocked users can use c2s connections:
  c2s: 
    blocked: deny
    all: allow
  ## For C2S connections, all users except admins use the "normal" shaper
  c2s_shaper: 
    admin: none
    all: normal
  ## All S2S connections use the "fast" shaper
  s2s_shaper: 
    all: fast
  ## Only admins can send announcement messages:
  announce: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only admins can use the configuration interface:
  configure: 
    admin: allow
  ## Admins of this server are also admins of the MUC service:
  muc_admin: 
    admin: allow
  ## Only accounts of the local ejabberd server can create rooms:
  muc_create: 
    local: allow
  ## All users are allowed to use the MUC service:
  muc: 
    all: allow
  ## Only accounts on the local ejabberd server can create Pubsub nodes:
  pubsub_createnode: 
    local: allow
  ## In-band registration allows registration of any possible username.
  ## To disable in-band registration, replace 'allow' with 'deny'.
  register: 
    all: allow
  ## Only allow to register from localhost
  trusted_network: 
    loopback: allow
  ## Do not establish S2S connections with bad servers
  ## s2s:
  ##   bad_servers: deny
  ##   all: allow

   ## By default the frequency of account registrations from the same IP
   ## is limited to 1 account every 10 minutes. To disable, specify: infinity
   ## registration_timeout: 600

   ##
   ## Define specific Access Rules in a virtual host.
```

Comment: Yes, probably it's a configuration thing: the developers of your ejabberd package may have disabled registration from outside localhost to prevent spam. So it's important to see the mod_register, acl and access options. Can you edit your post and copy the full configuration file?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the configuration file is shown above as you can see...and i can edit it as well to make it work

Comment: Can you suggest how can change this configuration  file?